How can I use the 'aws_subnets' data source to get all subnets without a tag that matches a pattern
Is it possible to use the aws_subnets data source to retrieve a list of subnets that either lack a tag entirely, or where the value of that tag does not match a pattern?
Currently I am having to use the aws_subnets data source to get two lists-

A list of all subnets.
A list of subnets Name tag that matches "name-to-exclude-*"

And finally I am having to use a local variable to create a new list of subnets that ARE included in list 1 above, but ARE NOT in list 2 above.
This seems inefficient. Is there a way to do this with just one data source?
data "aws_subnets" "all" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "exclude" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [var.vpc_id]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "name-to-exclude-*"
  }
}

locals {
  include_subnets = [for v in data.aws_subnets.all.ids: v
    if !contains(data.aws_subnets.exclude.ids, v)]
}


I believe the only efficiency gain here is the use of the setsubtract function instead of your use of a constructor with a for expression iterable generator with O(n) comparison conditionals:
locals {
  include_subnets = setsubtract(data.aws_subnets.all.ids, data.aws_subnets.exclude.ids)
}

You may need to explicitly recast those ids exported attributes types with toset() as the documentation claims the tftype for those is list, but Terraform should be capable of an implicit conversion.
If this is possible with AWS API filters and no Terraform data transformations then I would happily upvote that answer instead (probably requires a regular expression).

Thanks for pointing my towards setsubtract(), I wasn't aware of that function. I can't see anyway to do this with the AWS API filters either, looks like they only support wildcards (*) as opposed to full blown regexs.
